# Returning a bluebird promise to electrons renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, electron

Im using Electron's `remote` function to call a node module which returns a bluebird promise. However, I can't figure out how to get the promise returned back to the renderer process thats calling the module.

Using this code the value of `return_data1` is always empty.

```
 exports.call_python = function () {

     data1 = []

     var Promise = require('bluebird');
     var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

     function promiseFromChildProcess(child) {
         return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             child.addListener("error", reject);
             child.addListener("exit", resolve);
         });
     }

     var child = exec('ls');

     promiseFromChildProcess(child).then(function (result) {
         console.log('promise complete: ' + result);
     }, function (err) {
         console.log('promise rejected: ' + err);
     });

     child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
         console.log('stdout: ' + data);
         data.push={data: data}

     });
     child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
         console.log('stderr: ' + data);
     });
     child.on('close', function (code) {
         console.log('closing code: ' + code);
     });
     return data1
 };
```

Comment: Please remove the `java` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Once you jump into Promises it's pretty much promises all the way down. You can unwrap a Promise to get back to callback semantics but unless you are writing a service for pre-Promise API why would you?

In this case don't return data1; return the resolved promise. e.g.:

```
return promiseFromChildProcess(child).then(function (result) {
     console.log('promise complete: ' + result);
     return result; 
 }, function (err) {
     console.log('promise rejected: ' + err);
     return '';
 });
```

or if the client should deal with the error just:

```
return promiseFromChildProcess(child);
```

It sounds like maybe you are unsure of how to use child_process. The really simple way is to just grab stdout after the child process exits:

```
var b = require('bluebird');
var cp = require('child_process');

new b(function(resolve, reject){
    cp.exec('dir', function(err, stdout, stderr){
        resolve(stdout); 
    });
}).then(function(data){
    console.log("dir is "+data);
});
```

so do:

```
 exports.call_python = function () {
     var b = require('bluebird');
     var cp = require('child_process');

     return new b(function(resolve, reject){
        cp.exec('ls', function(err, stdout, stderr){
           resolve(stdout); 
        });
     });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. So this gets me back a pending promise in the electron renderer process. e.g. Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}. How do I get to the actual return value here ?

Comment: You also appear to have a bug in your code: `data.push={data: data}` should probably be `data1.push={data: data}` though really you should accumulate all the data and concatenate it in the child.end event

Comment: see further example for minimal example of collecting directory

Comment: OK so that works, but if I enclose your last example in function and call it how do I get the return the value for data ?

Comment: What part are you unclear about? My sample showed creating a promise and consuming the data in a then chain. Added another example

Comment: So I think my problem is that I'm calling the function using electron `remote` which itself is returning a pending promise. `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

Comment: If I do things synchronously e.g. `ChildProcess = require('child_process');
      return ChildProcess.execSync( 'ls' ).toString();` it works OK and I obviously don't need to use promises.